# Mutate column using array names

Tags: r, arrays, tidyverse, purrr, dplyr

**Context:** 
My data analysis involves manipulating ~100 different trials separately, and each trial has >1000 rows. Eventually, one step requires me to combine each trial with a column value from a different dataset. I plan to combine this dataset with each trial within an array using left_join() and "ID" as the key.

### Dilemma

I want to mutate() the trial name into a new column labeled "ID". I feel like this should be a simple task, but I'm still a novice when working with lists and arrays.

#### Working Code

I don't know how to share .csv files, but you can save the example datasets as .csv files within a practice folder named "data".

```
library(tidyverse)
# Create practice dataset
df1 <- tibble(Time  = seq(1, 5,  by = 1), 
              Point = seq(6, 10, by = 1)) %>% print()
# A tibble: 5 x 2
   Time Point
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     6
2     2     7
3     3     8
4     4     9
5     5    10
df2 <- tibble(Time  = seq(6, 10, by = 1), 
              Point = seq(1, 5,  by = 1)) %>% print()
# A tibble: 5 x 2
   Time Point
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     6     1
2     7     2
3     8     3
4     9     4
5    10     5
write_csv(df1, file.path("data", "21May27_CtYJ10.csv")
write_csv(df2, file.path("data", "21May27_HrOW07.csv"))
```

This is the code I have working right now:

```
# Isolate .csv files from directory into a list
rawFiles_List <- list.files("data", pattern = ".csv", full = TRUE) %>% print()
# Naming scheme for files w/n list
trialDate <- list(str_sub(rawFiles_List, 13, 26)) %>% 
  print() # Adjust the substring to include date and trial
[[1]]
[1] "21May27_CtYJ10" "21May27_HrOW07"

trial <- list(str_sub(rawFiles_List, 21, 26)) %>% print() # Only include trial
[[1]]
[1] "CtYJ10" "HrOW07"

# Combine the list and list names into an array
rawFiles <- array(map(rawFiles_List, read_csv), dimnames = trialDate) %>% print()
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  Time = col_double(),
  Point = col_double()
)
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  Time = col_double(),
  Point = col_double()
)
$`21May27_CtYJ10`
# A tibble: 5 x 2
   Time Point
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     6
2     2     7
3     3     8
4     4     9
5     5    10

$`21May27_HrOW07`
# A tibble: 5 x 2
   Time Point
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     6     1
2     7     2
3     8     3
4     9     4
5    10     5
```

This partially does what I want:

```
map(rawFiles, ~ data.frame(.) %>% # Convert to dataframe
      # Create a new column with trial name
      mutate(ID = map(trial, paste)) %>% # Pastes the list, not the respective value
      as_tibble(.)) # Convert back to tibble

$`21May27_CtYJ10`
# A tibble: 5 x 3
   Time Point MouseID  
  <dbl> <dbl> <list>   
1     1     6 <chr [2]>
2     2     7 <chr [2]>
3     3     8 <chr [2]>
4     4     9 <chr [2]>
5     5    10 <chr [2]>

$`21May27_HrOW07`
# A tibble: 5 x 3
   Time Point MouseID  
  <dbl> <dbl> <list>   
1     6     1 <chr [2]>
2     7     2 <chr [2]>
3     8     3 <chr [2]>
4     9     4 <chr [2]>
5    10     5 <chr [2]>
```

### Question:

Can you please help me make a new column filled with their respective trial IDs? I am trying to use mostly tidyverse functions, but I'm open to Base-R functions, too. If you are able to give some explanation as how you match the list elements to the array elements or refer me to a helpful resource, that would be much appreciated.

### Bonus Question:

I am working on how to save each file after all manipulations, but I'm not sure if I'm writing my for loop correctly. Could you provide some guidance as how I should edit my for loop? I'm using previous code as a guide, but I'm willing to scrap it if I'm over-complicating things. The following is what I have written so far:

```
SaveDate <- format(Sys.Date(), format = "%y%b%d")

for (i in 1:length(combFiles)) { # Dataset combing array of trials manipulated
  filename <- vector("list", length(rawFiles)) # Vector to fill
  filename[[i]] <- paste( # Fill vector with respective filenames
    as.data.frame(trial)[[1]][i], "_mod_", SaveDate, ".csv", sep = "")
  write.csv(file = filename[[i]],
            modFiles[[i]], # Array of trials manipulated
            sep = ",", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Does something like this help? `map2(rawFiles, trial, ~ data.frame(.x) %>%mutate(ID = .y)) %>% as_tibble(.))`

Comment: @GuedesBF I tried, but it did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Create practice dataset
df1 <- tibble(Time  = seq(1, 5,  by = 1), 
              Point = seq(6, 10, by = 1)) %>% print()
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>    Time Point
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     6
#> 2     2     7
#> 3     3     8
#> 4     4     9
#> 5     5    10

df2 <- tibble(Time  = seq(6, 10, by = 1), 
              Point = seq(1, 5,  by = 1)) %>% print()
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>    Time Point
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     6     1
#> 2     7     2
#> 3     8     3
#> 4     9     4
#> 5    10     5

write_csv(df1, "21May27_CtYJ10.csv")
write_csv(df2, "21May27_HrOW07.csv")

rm(df1, df2)
```

The easiest is to use `imap_*`. This will automatically loop on all the files in your list and combine them if needed. For this to work, the file list must have names.

```r
# Prepare raw file list with names equal to the values
rawFiles_List <- list.files(pattern = "^21May27") %>%
  set_names()
rawFiles_List
#>   21May27_CtYJ10.csv   21May27_HrOW07.csv 
#> "21May27_CtYJ10.csv" "21May27_HrOW07.csv"

imap_dfr(rawFiles_List,
        ~ read_csv(.x, col_types = "dd") %>%
          add_column(source_file = .y))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>     Time Point source_file       
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>             
#>  1     1     6 21May27_CtYJ10.csv
#>  2     2     7 21May27_CtYJ10.csv
#>  3     3     8 21May27_CtYJ10.csv
#>  4     4     9 21May27_CtYJ10.csv
#>  5     5    10 21May27_CtYJ10.csv
#>  6     6     1 21May27_HrOW07.csv
#>  7     7     2 21May27_HrOW07.csv
#>  8     8     3 21May27_HrOW07.csv
#>  9     9     4 21May27_HrOW07.csv
#> 10    10     5 21May27_HrOW07.csv
```

If you prefer to stay with a list of data frames and just add a column in each, use `imap()`:

```r
imap(rawFiles_List,
         ~ read_csv(.x, col_types = "dd") %>%
           add_column(source_file = .y))
#> $`21May27_CtYJ10.csv`
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>    Time Point source_file       
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>             
#> 1     1     6 21May27_CtYJ10.csv
#> 2     2     7 21May27_CtYJ10.csv
#> 3     3     8 21May27_CtYJ10.csv
#> 4     4     9 21May27_CtYJ10.csv
#> 5     5    10 21May27_CtYJ10.csv
#> 
#> $`21May27_HrOW07.csv`
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>    Time Point source_file       
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>             
#> 1     6     1 21May27_HrOW07.csv
#> 2     7     2 21May27_HrOW07.csv
#> 3     8     3 21May27_HrOW07.csv
#> 4     9     4 21May27_HrOW07.csv
#> 5    10     5 21May27_HrOW07.csv
```

Of course, if you manipulate the names of the filelist before running the `map` command, you can make sure the correct value is inserted in the column:

```r
rawFiles_List <- list.files(pattern = "^21May27") %>%
  set_names(str_sub(., 21L, 26L))
```

As for saving, I suggest you use `iwalk()`. I think your for loop is not doing what you want (you are reinitializing `filename` at each pass, erasing its previous content, probably not what you want).

Comment: This works! Thank you for giving me options, too. I'll probably keep everything separate, so I can save separate files. I appreciate your help!